# Android Studio determines credentials for GitHub as invalid

Tags: java, android, git, github, intellij-idea

I have already cloned repository into my computer from github. For clone I used GitHub client. After that I import my project in Android Studio and say about git linking in settings of Version Control.

[image]

Meantime my colleague push 1 commit into master branch and ask me for updating project. Usual situation.

After that I trying to update project and AS ask me about credentials

[image]

**I put correct credentials** and click OK. But I was confused when Android Studio ask me about entering credentials again and again, thought 3 times, and show error **Fetch failed**.

[image]

I try to pull and rebase via GitHub Shell client, and all was good. But when I trying to update my project via Android Studio it produces error above.

I really confused about this, maybe I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem using ssh link instead of https.